# Bash associative arrays and dynamically assign variables

Tags: arrays, bash

I faced with a very strange behavior.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A array_first=(
    [name]="Array 1"
    [message]="Hi there"
)

declare -A array_second=(
    [name]="Array 2"
    [message]="Bye!"
)

arrays=(array_first array_second)

for arr in ${!arrays[*]}
do
    val=${arrays[$arr]}
    val=${!val}
    echo ${val[name]} # Why this string is empty?
done

echo "${array_first[name]}"
echo "${array_first[message]}"

echo "${array_second[name]}"
echo "${array_second[message]}"
```

I need the value of an associative array, and displays an empty string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the ${!val}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When combining `${!...}` with arrays, you have to specify the index or key in the string you evaluate with `!`:

```
for arr in ${!arrays[*]}
do
    val=${arrays[$arr]}
    ex="$val[name]"
    echo ${!ex} # No longer empty.
done
```